# absolutely positioned logo not centeredd in iOS

Tags: ios, css-position

The logo on my friends website is working properly in all browsers yet when I open up my iPhone or iPad (actual devices) it's all wonky.

```
<a href="http://www.averylawoffice.ca/averywordpress"><img class="averylogo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/HEADER-AveryLawOffice-LOGO.png" alt="Avery Law Office"></a>
```

It's not placed in any containing div. Just on it's own.

CSS

```
 .averylogo { position: absolute; width:360px; left: 50%; margin-left: -180px; z-index: 2; }
```

I'm not quite sure why it works everywhere else but doesn't center on my iPad or iPhone properly.

This is what it's looking like, but only on the iOS.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `#main-navigation` `position:relative;` otherwise the logo is positioned relative to the body, which is resized on your smaller device.

Chris Coyier has an [article about it](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

Comment: There is one thin I have just seen. In IE the logo now appears behind the banner. I'm assuming it's because the logo is now relative and sits behind the banner. How can I make it on top of the banner in IE?

Comment: You could give `nav{ z-index:20;}` and `#banner{ z-index: 10}` (see: http://jsfiddle.net/Sdgz3/3/show/ ) . On a side note, it's not good practice to have multiple elements with the same id (I noticed you have `#banner > #banner` )

Comment: Okay. That worked. I'll have to brush up on my CSS! And thanks for pointing that out. I don't usually do something like that but I guess I forgot to take out the <div id="banner"> in the functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left: auto` and remove `left: 50%`.

You may want to add `text-align: center` to `#main-navigation` for IE.